# From two array get unique value in third array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

I have two javascript arrays object like below

First array:

```
count_array[0].left= 0;
count_array[0].width= 33;
count_array[0].id= 1;
count_array[1].left= "";
count_array[1].width= "";
count_array[1].id= 2;
count_array[2].left= "";
count_array[2].width= "";
count_array[2].id= 3;
```

Second array:

```
temp_array[0].left= "";
temp_array[0].width= "";
temp_array[0].id= 4;
temp_array[1].left= "";
temp_array[1].width= "";
temp_array[1].id= 5;
temp_array[2].left= 0;
temp_array[2].width= 33;
temp_array[2].id= 1;
```

I want to get array which has unique value of id in javascript from above two array like below

Third array:

```
temp_array_cnt[0].left= 0;
temp_array_cnt[0].width= 33;
temp_array_cnt[0].id= 1;
```

I am using below code but it is not working

```
function intersection(x,y){
  x.sort();y.sort();
 var i=j=0;ret=[];
 while(i<x.length && j<y.length){
  if(x[i]<y[j])i++;
  else if(y[j]<x[i])j++;
  else {
    ret.push(x[i]);
    i++,j++;
   }
  }
 return ret;
```

}

Please help me here.
Thanks

I am using below function now

```
   function intersection(x,y){
ret=[];
//x.sort();y.sort();
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
 for(var j=0;j<y.length;i++)
 {
    //console.log(x[i].eventid);
    var chk_left=x[i];
    if(chk_left.id == chk_left.id)
    {
        ret.push(chk_left);
    }
 }
}
   return ret;
   }
```

But it gives me error like this "id is null or not an object".

Comment: are you trying to combine two arrays? why you doing this x[i]<y[j]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var temp = 0;

for(var i=0;i<count_array.length;i++)
{
for(var j=0;j<temp_array.length;i++)
{
if(count_array[i].id == temp_array[j].id)
{
temp_array_cnt[temp].left= count_array[i].left;
temp_array_cnt[temp].width= count_array[i].width;
temp_array_cnt[temp].id= count_array[i].id;
temp++;
}
}
}
```